# RAM consumption is too high after upgrading

Tags: firefox, update-manager, browser, ram-usage

I got a security update recently from ubuntu. After installing, RAM consumption is high.
I could work with firefox and VS code together by opening 4 or 5 tabs in my system, but now I can't open any browser and software together.
When I checked the system monitor, ram usage was more than double that of the earlier case. Whenever I try to open a browser with any software, the system will freeze. What should I do to solve this?

Comment: Are you using a supported Ubuntu release? Which? Read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: Please, give detailed information about your hardware and software config (at least Ubuntu version). Avoid using relative (e.g. _"double"_) metrics; instead give real values.

Comment: please edit your computers specs into your question,how much ram is used?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1401883/does-ubuntu-has-memory-leaks